# Nothing showing in Grafana for Spring Boot 3 opentelemetry-javaagent - version: 1.32.0 via Open Telemetry Collector

Tags: spring-boot, open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, open-telemetry-java

Environment: Spring Boot 3.2.0, JDK 17, Micrometer 1.12.0

[image: Micro Meter]

First time user of Open Telemetry.

Auto configuration using opentelemetry-javaagent - version: 1.32.0

Each microservice is an OAuth2 resource and the actuator endpoints are protected. Meaning, I cannot pull metrics from prometheus jobs hitting the actuator endpoints.

Basically, taking the default grpc which defaults to exporting logging, tracing and metrics to localhost:4317

```
export OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=ingest
export OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=service.namespace\=osint,deployment.environment\=local
export OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:4317"
export OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_PROTOCOL=grpc
export OTEL_LOGS_EXPORTER=logging-otlp
export OTEL_METRICS_EXPORTER=logging-otlp
export OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=logging-otlp
```

Appling the Micrometer Registry/Open Telemetry Registry fix:
[Bridging OpenTelemetry and Micrometer](https://grafana.com/blog/2022/05/04/how-to-capture-spring-boot-metrics-with-the-opentelemetry-java-instrumentation-agent/)

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnClass(name = "io.opentelemetry.javaagent.OpenTelemetryAgent")
    public MeterRegistry otelRegistry() {
        Optional<MeterRegistry> otelRegistry = Metrics.globalRegistry.getRegistries().stream()
            .filter(r -> r.getClass().getName().contains("OpenTelemetryMeterRegistry"))
            .findAny();
        otelRegistry.ifPresent(Metrics.globalRegistry::remove);
        return otelRegistry.orElse(null);
    }
```

I am getting logs from OtlpJsonLoggingSpanExporter and OtlpJsonLoggingLogRecordExporter and OtlpJsonLoggingMetricExporter with the json payload.

The problem seems to be in the OTEL Collector configuration and I can't seem to get any logging diagnostics to work. I am sure it is a configuration thing.

I am patterning it off [Spring Boot using OpenTelemetry, Prometheus, Grafana, Tempo, and Loki](https://medium.com/@ahmadalammar/comprehensive-observability-in-spring-boot-using-opentelemetry-prometheus-grafana-tempo-and-067196eee539) which are the backends we intend to use:

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'


services:
  loki:
    container_name: loki
    image: grafana/loki:latest
    command: [ "-config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml" ]
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"

  prometheus:
    container_name: prometheus
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    volumes:
      - ${OSI_DOCKER_ROOT}\prometheus\prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    command:
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"

  tempo:
    container_name: tempo
    image: grafana/tempo:latest
    command: [ "-config.file=/etc/tempo.yml" ]
    volumes:
      - ${OSI_DOCKER_ROOT}\tempo\tempo.yml:/etc/tempo.yml:ro
      - ${OSI_DOCKER_ROOT}\tempo\tempo-data:/tmp/tempo
    ports:
      - "3200:3200"  # Tempo see tempo.yml http_listen_port
      - "4317"  # otlp grpc

  otel-collector:
    container_name: opentelemetry-collector
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib:0.82.0
    restart: always
    command:
      - "--config=/etc/otel/config.yml"
    volumes:
      - ${OSI_DOCKER_ROOT}\collector\otel-collector-config.yml:/etc/otel/config.yml
    ports:
      - 1888:1888 # pprof extension
      - 8889:8889 # Prometheus metrics exposed by the Collector
      - 8890:8890 # Prometheus exporter metrics
      - 13133:13133 # health_check extension
      - 4317:4317 # OTLP gRPC receiver
      - 4318:4318 # OTLP http receiver
      - 55679:55679 # zpages extension
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
      - tempo
      - loki


  grafana:
    container_name: grafana
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    environment:
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
      - GF_AUTH_DISABLE_LOGIN_FORM=true
    volumes:
      - ./grafana:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources:ro
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
      - tempo
      - loki
      - otel-collector
```

**collector:**

```
extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
  zpages:

############ Receivers from application
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      http:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4318
      grpc:
        endpoint: 0.0.0.0:4317

processors:
  # batch metrics before sending to reduce API usage
  batch:
    send_batch_max_size: 1000
    send_batch_size: 100
    timeout: 10s
  #https://community.grafana.com/t/error-sending-logs-with-loki-resource-labels/87561/2

######### From processor, export to Logging, tracing and/or metrics servers
exporters:
  logging:
    verbosity: detailed
  #Metrics to Prometheus
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "0.0.0.0:8889"
    const_labels:
      label1: osint
  # tracing to tempo
  otlp:
    endpoint: tempo:4317
    tls:
      insecure: true
  # logging to loki
  loki:
    endpoint: "http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push"

# The Collector pipeline.
service:
  telemetry:
    logs:
      level: debug
      development: true
      sampling:
        initial: 10
        thereafter: 5
      output_paths:
        - stdout
      error_output_paths:
        - stderr
    metrics:
      level: detailed
  extensions: [health_check, pprof, zpages]
  pipelines:
    # for now we only interested about metrics...
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [prometheus]
    traces:
      receivers: [ otlp ]
      processors: [ batch ]
      exporters: [ otlp ]  # name here should match the exporter name for tempo which is otlp
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [loki, logging]
```

**prometheus:**

```
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s
  evaluation_interval: 15s
 
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['prometheus:9090']  #docker-compose prometheus port
```

**tempo:**

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 3200

distributor:
  receivers:                           # this configuration will listen on all ports and protocols that tempo is capable of.
    zipkin:
    jaeger:                            # the receivers all come from the OpenTelemetry collector.  more configuration information can
      protocols:                       # be found there: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/tree/main/receiver
        thrift_http:                   #
        grpc:                          # for a production deployment you should only enable the receivers you need!
        thrift_binary:
        thrift_compact:
    otlp:
      protocols:
        http:
        grpc:
    opencensus:

ingester:
  max_block_duration: 5m               # cut the headblock when this much time passes. this is being set for demo purposes and should probably be left alone normally

compactor:
  compaction:
    block_retention: 1h                # overall Tempo trace retention. set for demo purposes

metrics_generator:
  registry:
    external_labels:
      source: tempo
      cluster: docker-compose
  storage:
    path: /tmp/tempo/generator/wal

storage:
  trace:
    backend: local                     # backend configuration to use
    wal:
      path: /tmp/tempo/wal             # where to store the wal locally
    local:
      path: /tmp/tempo/blocks

overrides:
  metrics_generator_processors: [service-graphs, span-metrics] # enables metrics generator
```

http://localhost:4318/v1/traces

```
{
  "resource": {
    "attributes": [
      {
        "key": "deployment.environment",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "local"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "host.arch",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "amd64"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "host.name",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "BRANDA-BSTAQ-PC"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "os.description",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "Windows 10 10.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "os.type",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "windows"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "process.command_line",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "C:\\sfw\\java\\jdk17.0.7_7\\bin\\java.exe -javaagent:./agent/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Xverify:none -Dspring.profiles.active=local, local-otel -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true -javaagent:C:\\Program Files\\IntelliJ IDEA 2020\\lib\\idea_rt.jar=57806:C:\\Program Files\\IntelliJ IDEA 2020\\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 com.osi.ingest.IngestApplication"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "process.executable.path",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "C:\\sfw\\java\\jdk17.0.7_7\\bin\\java.exe"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "process.pid",
        "value": {
          "intValue": "4032"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "process.runtime.description",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "Amazon.com Inc. OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17.0.7+7-LTS"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "process.runtime.name",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "OpenJDK Runtime Environment"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "process.runtime.version",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "17.0.7+7-LTS"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "service.name",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "ingest"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "service.namespace",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "osint"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "telemetry.auto.version",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "1.32.0"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "telemetry.sdk.language",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "java"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "telemetry.sdk.name",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "opentelemetry"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "telemetry.sdk.version",
        "value": {
          "stringValue": "1.32.0"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "scopeSpans": [
    {
      "scope": {
        "name": "io.opentelemetry.java-http-client",
        "version": "1.32.0-alpha",
        "attributes": []
      },
      "spans": [
        {
          "traceId": "449f8711153cf82b2e2ce8d7bbeaca2c",
          "spanId": "62405db1f5d0c262",
          "name": "POST",
          "kind": 3,
          "startTimeUnixNano": "1706304807905937000",
          "endTimeUnixNano": "1706304807995062800",
          "attributes": [
            {
              "key": "thread.id",
              "value": {
                "intValue": "34"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "net.peer.name",
              "value": {
                "stringValue": "localhost"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "http.status_code",
              "value": {
                "intValue": "204"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "net.protocol.version",
              "value": {
                "stringValue": "1.1"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "thread.name",
              "value": {
                "stringValue": "loki4j-sender-0"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "http.method",
              "value": {
                "stringValue": "POST"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "net.peer.port",
              "value": {
                "intValue": "3100"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "net.protocol.name",
              "value": {
                "stringValue": "http"
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "http.url",
              "value": {
                "stringValue": "http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/push"
              }
            }
          ],
          "events": [],
          "links": [],
          "status": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "schemaUrl": "https://opentelemetry.io/schemas/1.21.0"
}
```

Results in: 200 OK

```
{
    "partialSuccess": {}
}
```

Same with http://localhost:4318/v1/metrics and http://localhost:4318/v1/logs

Collector logs:

```
024-01-26 11:32:09 2024-01-26T18:32:09.739Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [transport] [server-transport 0xc000e4cb60] Closing: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"POST /api/v2/spans HTTP/\""    {"grpc_log": true}
2024-01-26 11:32:09 2024-01-26T18:32:09.739Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Server #1] grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"POST /api/v2/spans HTTP/\"" {"grpc_log": true}
2024-01-26 14:36:44 2024-01-26T21:36:44.322Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [transport] [server-transport 0xc000e4d040] Closing: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"POST /api/v2/logs HTTP/1\""    {"grpc_log": true}
2024-01-26 14:36:44 2024-01-26T21:36:44.322Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Server #1] grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"POST /api/v2/logs HTTP/1\"" {"grpc_log": true}
2024-01-26 14:39:03 2024-01-26T21:39:03.649Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [transport] [server-transport 0xc000e4d040] Closing: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"POST /api/v2/logs HTTP/1\""    {"grpc_log": true}
2024-01-26 14:39:03 2024-01-26T21:39:03.649Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Server #1] grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"POST /api/v2/logs HTTP/1\"" {"grpc_log": true}
2024-01-26 14:48:45 2024-01-26T21:48:45.878Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [transport] [server-transport 0xc000e4d040] Closing: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"POST /api/v2/spans HTTP/\""    {"grpc_log": true}
2024-01-26 14:48:45 2024-01-26T21:48:45.878Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Server #1] grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"POST /api/v2/spans HTTP/\"" {"grpc_log": true}
2024-01-26 14:56:21 2024-01-26T21:56:21.866Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [transport] [server-transport 0xc000e4d040] Closing: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"POST /api/v2/metrics HTT\""    {"grpc_log": true}
2024-01-26 14:56:21 2024-01-26T21:56:21.866Z    info    zapgrpc/zapgrpc.go:178  [core] [Server #1] grpc: Server.Serve failed to create ServerTransport: connection error: desc = "transport: http2Server.HandleStreams received bogus greeting from client: \"POST /api/v2/metrics HTT\"" {"grpc_log": true}
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. It shouldn't be a list of keywords.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to stitch together metrics, traces and logs via Grafana. Might be worth checking out tools which have all the 3 in a single pane. https://github.com/signoz/signoz is one such project

Comment: @pranay01 I looked at https://signoz.io/blog/opentelemetry-spring-boot/ unfortunately I am not ready to introduce yet another level of complexity with SigNoz and not sure I want to hassle with getting SigNoz approved in our stack.

Comment: Updated with oltp logging and manual posts to collector

Comment: In your java application, do you have the autoconfiguration? https://opentelemetry.io/docs/languages/java/instrumentation/#automatic-configuration

Also, not sure what is `logging-otlp`, couldn't find documentation for this method adding two exporters.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently and was able to fix it by moving to the latest version of `io.micrometer`. The javagent automatically attaches `OpenTelemetryMeterRegistry` if the micrometer version is above `1.5` [Ref](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/3213c867847e26a8ef215807576ae0195a93ee54/instrumentation/micrometer/micrometer-1.5/javaagent/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/javaagent/instrumentation/micrometer/v1_5/MicrometerInstrumentationModule.java#L33)

As per my understanding the OTEL javaagent automatically sends the metrics collected by `OpenTelemetryMeterRegistry` to the OTEL collector. Which should enable your Grafana visualisation.

Comment: Updated Question to using Micrometer 1.12.0

Comment: Abandoned approach and went with Spring Boot 3 Instrumentation to push metrics, traces and logs to collector.

Comment: I would still recommend going with the javaagent approach since its very minimal and non intrusive to the codebase.